# jQuery how to move main navigation bar down on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a menu bar. The sub menu opens upward.
I want the following changes

1. On hover main navigation bar should move down and sub link bar should be visible upwards.
2. The sub menu bar should hide if mouse out of main navigation and main navigation should again move upwards.
3. The sub link bar should hide on page scroll and main navigation should be upward.

The link for [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xCuLq/)

HTML code is

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="table">

        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Home</b>
                </a></li></ul>



        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Joseph Turner</b><!--[if IE 7]><!-->           </a><!--<![endif]-->
                <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
                <div class="select_sub">
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Fishermen at Sea</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Shipwreck</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Vale of Ashburnham</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Crossing the Brook</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="select_sub"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>John Constable</b><!--[if IE        7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
                <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
                <div class="select_sub show">
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Hay Wain</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Brighton Beach</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Malvern Hall</a></li>
                        <li class="sub_show"><a href="#nogo">Salisbury Cathedral</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Weymouth Bay</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
            </li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Henri Matisse</b><!--[if IE 7]><!-->       </a><!--<![endif]-->
                <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
                <div class="select_sub">
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Girl with Green Eyes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Dream</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Woman in Blue</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Yellow Dress</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Piano Lesson</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
            </li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="select"><li><a href="#nogo"><b>Paul Cezanne</b><!--[if IE 7]><!-->              </a><!--<![endif]-->
                <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
                <div class="select_sub">
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="#nogo">The Large Bathers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Onions and Bottles</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Mardi Gras</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Still Life</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#nogo">Boy in a Red Waistcoat</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

css is

```
.nav {
    height:35px; 
    background: #854; 
    position:relative; 
    font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif; 
    font-size:11px; 
    width:750px; 
    z-index:500;


}

.nav .table {
    display:table; 
    margin:0 auto;
}

.nav .select,
.nav .current {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none; 
    display:table-cell; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.nav li {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    height:auto; 
    float:left;
}

.nav .select a {
    display:block; 
    height:35px; 
    float:left; 
    background: #632; 
    padding:0 30px 0 30px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    line-height:35px; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    color:#ddd;
}

.nav .current a {
    display:block; 
    height:35px; 
    float:left; 
    background: #134; 
    padding:0 0 0 15px; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    line-height:35px; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    color:#fff;
}


.nav .current a b {
    display:block; 
    padding:0 30px 0 15px; 
    background:#542 right top;
}

.nav .select a:hover, 
.nav .select li:hover a {
    background: #653; 
    padding:0 0 0 15px; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    color:#fff;
}

.nav .select a:hover b, 
.nav .select li:hover a b {
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    padding:0 30px 0 15px; 
    background:url(http://eurekavi.com/pro_line_1.gif) right top; 
    cursor:pointer;
}

.nav .select_sub {
    display:none;
}

/* IE6 only */
.nav table {
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    margin:-1px; 
    font-size:1em; 
    width:0; 
    height:0;
}

.nav .sub {
    display:table; 
    /*margin:0 auto; */
    /*padding:0; */
    list-style:none;
    background:#248;
    margin-top:-70px;
}

.nav .sub_active .current_sub a, 
.nav .sub_active a:hover {
    background:transparent; 
    color:#f00;
}

.nav .select :hover .select_sub, 
.nav .current .show {
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:750px; 
    top:35px; 
    background: #412; 
    padding:0; 
    z-index:100; 
    left:0; 
    text-align:center;
}

.nav .current .show {
    z-index:10;
}

.nav .select :hover .sub li a, 
.nav .current .show .sub li a {
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    background:transparent; 
    padding:0 10px 0 10px; 
    margin:0; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    border:0; 
    color:#444;
}

.nav .current .sub li.sub_show a {
    color:#088; 
    cursor:default; 
    background:#632;
}

.nav .select :hover .sub li a:hover, 
.nav .current .sub li a:hover {
    visibility:visible; 
    color:#088; 
    background:#743;
}
```

Please reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1 . To move the main menu down, initially set `top: 0;`
then you can use either .css() or .animate() jQuery methods

example:

`$(".nav").animate({top: "30px"}, 500);`

2 . trigger the above code in your onmouseover event of your menu item and you can use

`$(".nav").animate({top: "0px"}, 500);` for onmouseout event

In your HTML you can add,

```
<div class="nav" onmouseover="movedown()">....</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function movedown() {
    $(".nav").animate({top: "30px"}, 500);
}
</script>`
```

3 . You need not use a scroll event because onmouseout event will automatically hide your sub menu

4 . To prevent main menu from hiding, put a time delay on the onmouseout event and make use of flags.

Here's the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ExaLM/4/

**Read topics:**

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

**See this for an example:**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover

Comment: Hi, I updated a new fiddle 

jsfiddle.net/ExaLM/1

Now the main navigation bar is closing on mouse leave event. 

But if I hover on sub link bar then also sub link bar closes.

So what changes should I make in my code for that?